# Expansion of square root of a sum

Tags: calculus, exponentiation

I know that $(a +  b)^2$ can be expanded as $(a + b) * (a + b) = a^2 + 2ab + b^2$.

Is there an equivalent **expansion method for the square root of a sum**, that is, $(a +  b)^{1/2}$?

If there's no *method*, how could one derive these equalities? $$(x + dx)^{1/2} = x^{1/2}(1 + \frac{dx}{x})^{1/2} = \sqrt{x} + \frac{1}{2}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x}} ....$$
Attached is a screenshot for more information.[image]

Comment: Where did you see such an expansion? Do you know Taylor's series?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series for a formula to expand $(1+t)^{\alpha}$ for arbitrary $\alpha \in \Bbb{C}$.

Comment: It's from a book called "Calculus Made Easy" by Silvanus Thompson. I think I heard of Taylor's series but I'm clueless about it. Is that a hint of the answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Taylor series of $\sqrt{1+x}$ about $x = 0$ converges for $|x| ≤ 1$, and is given by
$$
{\displaystyle {\sqrt {1+x}}=\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }{\frac {(-1)^{n}(2n)!}{(1-2n)(n!)^{2}(4^{n})}}x^{n}=1+{\frac {1}{2}}x-{\frac {1}{8}}x^{2}+\cdots ,}
$$

This is where the formal identity $(1+\frac{dx}{x})^{1/2}$ from.

---

The first formal identity is nothing but
$$
(a+b)^{1/2}=[a(1+\frac{b}{a})]^{1/2}=a^{1/2}[1+\frac{b}{a}]^{1/2}
$$
assuming all the quantities are positive.

Comment: isn't there a binomial expansion formula for this as well?

Comment: @CSquared: the definition of "binomial expansion" is from the Taylor series.